# how to download and install teradata on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, teradata

Can any one help me install "Teradata" on Windows 10. A step by step guide will be much helpful.

I tried this in Google but didnt get any useful link.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "install" Teradata on Windows, there's no more Windows version since TD14.

There's only a VM running TD on Suse Enterprise Linux in different flavours found on the [Teradata Download site](http://downloads.teradata.com/download) (The [user guide](http://developer.teradata.com/database/articles/teradata-express-14-0-for-vmware-user-guide) is a bit outdated, but still valid), for [VMWare Player](http://downloads.teradata.com/node/7671), [VMware vSphere](http://developer.teradata.com/node/196605) and the new [trial on AWS](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express/amazon-ec2).

.

Comment: So , is there any way to learn teradata on my laptop. I was trying to set up teradata on my windows machine (I have only windows , no linux in my laptop). Or is there any online editor available for teradata.

Comment: Yes, install the VMware version of Teradata Express or use the trial on AWS as mentioned by @dnoeth.